# Not able to parameterize the link and give as href to the mentioned frame location

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to parameterize the href link which so I am passing variable from PHP loop. but when I click on text it doesnot taking exact url and showing url is invalid in the another frame. when i print the parameterized link and stored as link in document.write() but is not taking as href. how can it be done? Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function trial(a,b) {

        var link='http://localhost/DashboardAsPerCustomer/BlackLotus_'+a+'_hello.php';
        //document.write(link);

        parent.table.location.href='link';

    }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>This is special</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <?php
        $names=array("Prajna","Vidya","Deepak","Yajana","Mahadev","Latika","Uzma");
        $y=10;

        for($x=0;$x<count($names);$x++)
        {
            echo'<form method="post"><p onClick="trial('.$x.','.$y.');">'.$names[$x].'</p></form><p>';
        }
        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Below file is to set 4 different frames and when onclick happen on text which is printing in php loop in above program it calls javascript function with passing parameters and it opens the perticular parameterized link on the 3rd frame.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <frameset rows="13%,87%,*%">
        <frame src="header.php" scrolling=no >
        <frameset cols="20%,80%,*%" >

          <frame src="phpinsidephp.php" name="tree" >

            <frameset rows="40%,60%,*%">
              <frame src="http://localhost/JqueryAjax/chart4.php" name="table" scrolling=yes >
              <frame src="Tables\project_table.php" name="graph" scrolling=no >  
            </frameset>

        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use frames? this is 2017 now, not 1996 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must assign variable `link` not string `'link'`

```
parent.table.location.href=link;
```

Comment: Check solved anwers, If you dont know only must check the tick on left the anwers :)